# Перебор ассоциативного массива php

Tags: php

Есть массив типа

```
Array

[1] => Array
    (
        [PRODUCT_ID] => 381636
        [QUANTITY] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PRODUCT_ID] => 488928
        [QUANTITY] => 1
    )
```

)

Мне нужно каждый массив циклом записать в переменную 
Bitrix\Catalog\Product\Basket::addProduct($arrPos2);

Например: Сначала $arrPos2 будет равна Array
        (
            [PRODUCT_ID] => 381636
            [QUANTITY] => 1
        )

Потом $arrPos2 будет равна Array
        (
            [PRODUCT_ID] => 488928
            [QUANTITY] => 1
        )

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Первый же результат в google по строке "Перебор ассоциативного массива php" даст ответ на вопрос.

Comment: вы `foreach`, `for` или `while` не в состоянии написать что ли?

Comment: Я думаю этот вопрос должен быть в рубрике Юмор

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(data as $arrPos2){
 Bitrix\Catalog\Product\Basket::addProduct($arrPos2);
}
```

где data твой входной массив.

все же просто читай доку https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php